# How do we prepare the electron state $|s=1/2,s_z=+1/2\rangle$ in the laboratory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-spin, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-states

If we are interested in preparing the electron state $|+\rangle=|s=1/2,s_z=+1/2\rangle$ in the laboratory, the obvious thing is to apply a magnetic field along the positive $z$-axis (${\vec B}=B\hat{z}$). Having done that, can we be sure that the resulting state is $|1/2,+1/2\rangle$ but not $|1/2,-1/2\rangle$? I have a doubt that the electron could also be locked in the state $|1/2,-1/2\rangle$. After all, it is also an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian with ${\vec B}=B\hat{z}$.

Comment: What’s $1/2$ for $z$ is $-1/2$ for $-z$

Comment: I have changed to notation. Does that answer your query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Stern-Gerlach apparatus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment) uses a non-uniform magnetic field to physically separate the incoming beam of electrons into two. All you have to do is block one of the beams with a barrier. The remaining beam is pure $|s=1/2,m_s=+1/2\rangle$ (or pure $|s=1/2,m_s=-1/2\rangle$, depending on which beam you block).